# Nginx + Symfony 4 + Subfolder = issue

Tags: symfony, nginx, networking, debian, fpm

I have a problem with nginx and Symfony

I have a symfony app and it works when i follow the doc but i would like to make something like this
`http://website.com/symfonyapp1` and `http://website.com/symfonyapp2`

here is my nginx config :

```
server {


server_name website.com;

   location /symfonyapp1{
      root /var/www/html/symfonyapp1/public;
      # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
      try_files $uri symfonyapp1 /index.php$is_args$args;

   }
   location ~ ^/symfonyapp1/public/index\.php(/|$) {
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
       internal;
   }
}
```

here is my /etc/hosts file

```
XXX.XXX.XX.XX   website1.local  symfonyapp1
XXX.XXX.XX.XX   website2.local  symfonyapp2
```

if someone can help me it can be very helpful

Thanks in advance